# How did I manage to flag this question twice?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, flagging, vote-to-close

I flagged [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187835/what-assembly-should-i-learn) question as primarily-opinion based however, it is now showing that I flagged it as a duplicate:

[image]

along with the original flag.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 5):

It isn't showing that you flagged as a duplicate. It's showing that you flagged for *recommended closure*, and this disables both flagging as “should be closed” and flagging as a duplicate. “Duplicate” and “should be closed” are both recommended closure flags.